# Diff between files : Diff from column x

Tags: python, diff

I have  to take the code diff of 2 (gcov) files, which have counters  infront of each lines.

Basically i need to ignore the first few(x) columns and then take the diff for the rest of the content

Ex:

File:1

```
1        printf("Stack Overflow"); 
1        if(condition) 
#####       printf("Stack");
         else
1            printf("Overflow");
```

File 2:

```
1        printf("Stack Overflow"); 
1        if(condition) 
#####       printf("Overflow");
         else
1            printf("Stack");
```

I can strip the counters infront of each of the lines &  edit the file (or create a new files). But, i am looking for some options wherein we don't have to change the files(or create new ones) for getting the code diff. Trying to use Python for this.

Comment: Isn't there some linux command to strip the first columns off, then use the results for `diff`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie is right. `sed 's/^.....//'` removes first 5 characters of each line. And the `diff` command will give you the difference.